# Remove .Net from Ubuntu 20.04 completely

Tags: 20.04, uninstall, dotnet

I was trying debugging options in Visual Studio Code for C#. But there's a message at the bottom right every time I open VB Code, which says,

> The .NET Core SDK cannot be located. .NET Core debugging will not be
> enabled. Make sure the .NET Core SDK is installed and is on the path.

Now I want to remove and reinstall .Net but couldn't uninstall it. I've tried the following commands,

```
sudo apt remove --purge dotnet-sdk-5.0.201
```

and

```
sudo apt remove --purge dotnet-runtime-5.0.201
```

How can I completely remove .Net?

Comment: Hi and welcome. Please do not show pictures of text include them in the question.

Comment: @Kulfy removing .201 does not help

Comment: "but couldn't uninstall it" why not? I am missing 2 things: how did you install it and what is the error message. If you did not use apt to install apt purge is the wrong tool to remove. if you get a package not found the name is wrong.

Comment: Ok it says "Unable to locate package" but I can't remember how did I install it

Comment: I may have used this command `sudo snap install dotnet-sdk --classic`

Comment: @user68186 The problem is solved. Thanks.

Answer (score 1):

The problem was solved just with the re-installation of .NET and Visual Studio Code.
Previously installed .NET was removed with `sudo snap remove --purge dotnet-sdk` command.

VS Code was removed from snap store.

To reinstall .NET the process described in [Microsoft Documentation](https://docs.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/core/install/linux-snap) was followed. I then installed sdk and runtime both from snap store.

Answer (score 0):

I had troubles using just those two commands only on Linux as well. I think it is a bit more thorough to remove all the associated libraries as well. I had previously been playing with the pre-release version of .NET 8 and reinstalled to .NET 7.00 for another project by doing the following:

```
sudo apt remove --purge dotnet-*
```

Then reinstalling with the particular .NET sdk. I would imagine it might be more thorough if you previously used snap to do a similar removal:

```
sudo snap remove --purge dotnet-*
```

Although I'm not that familiar with snap and whether it supports wildcards.